# Does javascript have a shorthand way of setting up fields in an object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the following:

```
var link = {};
link.action = $link.attr('data-action') || '';
link.dialogType = $link.attr('data-dialogType') || '';
link.params = $link.attr('data-params') || '';
link.title = $link.attr('title') || '';
link.viewURL = $link.attr('data-href') || '';
link.entity = $link.attr('data-entity') || '';
link.row = $link.attr('data-row');
```

But is there a better way to do this?

Comment: `var link = {action: ..., dialogType: ..., params: ..., title: ... };`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var link = {
   action : $link.data('action') || '',
   dialogType : $link.data('dialogType') || '',
   params : $link.data('params') || '', 
   title : $link.attr('title') || '', 
   viewURL : $link.data('href') || '', 
   entity : $link.data('entity') || '',
   row : $link.data('row') 
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use dataset property.

> Allows access, both in reading and writing mode, to all the custom data attributes (data-*) set on the element. It is a map of DOMString, one entry for each custom data attribute.

```
var elm = $link[0], data = elm.dataset, link = { title: elm.title };
for (var i in data) link[i] = data[i]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AdzE3/